# How can I add value to existing textbox in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following `TextBlock`:

```
  <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Vertical" Text="Name" />
```

This is the `TextBlock` for my button on which I want to display name and value.

I want to display text on the button as Name[some_value].
I'm getting this this `some_value` run-time from some function. How can I print the value here?

Comment: Use Binding. Bind the string property and implement INotify changed in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `ViewModel` of that `View`:

```
private string _buttonValue;
public string ButtonValue{
get {return _buttonValue;}
}
```

Go to `constructor` and write down:

```
_buttonValue = "Name " + put_here_SomeValue_Runtime_Value;
```

Now, to to .`xaml`
Bind like belw:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ButtonValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: @Dannie: You can start learning from http://www.wpftutorial.net/ it has started WPF from basic.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're not yet familiar with `Binding` in XAML.

You can read, and see examples on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx).